# JQuery if mouse leaves div and is also not hovering another div do X

Tags: jquery, mouseleave

So I am trying to fire an event when my mouse leaves a particular div: `#div`, also only fire the event if the mouse is not currently hovering `#div2`.

I am trying to piece together a solution and this is what I have currently:

```
$("body").on('mouseleave', '#div', function(e){
    if( e.target.id != 'div2' && !$('div2').find(e.target).length) {
        //Action Here
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you. You have access to the mouse position as you leave the div through `e.clientX` and `e.clientY`. You can compare this mouse position to the bounding box of the second div to see if you've entered that div or not.

```
$("#div1").mouseleave(function (e) {

...

if (e.clientX >= left && e.clientY >= top && e.clientX <= right && e.clientY <= bottom) {
    //you're in div 2! add an else to do something if you're NOT entering div2 
    //or negate this condition
}

});
```

Here is a fiddle to illustrate how this works

http://jsfiddle.net/2jRC8/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var hovering = false;

$("#div").mouseleave(function () {
    if(!hovering) {
        //Action Here
    }
});

$("#div2").mouseenter(function () {
    hovering = true;
});
$("#div2").mouseleave(function () {
    hovering = false;
});
```

This will set a boolean equal to true if you are hovering over `#div2`. Now your action inside your `#div` mouse leave function should only run when you are outside `#div2`.

Comment: Doesn't really work. mouseleave fires before mouseenter does. This means hovering is always false. though, it may work sometimes if there is a race condition involved. However, in my tests, it appears that the events are always fired in this order.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` are binding listeners to the `#div2` that way when you mouse in or mouse out the div the content inside will run. The code I supplied isn't meant to be copied right into the file, you may need to slightly modify it. However this should work fine for what the OP supplied for code.

Comment: The #div mouseleave event fires before the #div2 mouseenter event. This means that when you move from div1 to div2, hovering is set to false. So the "//action here" code executes even though it shouldn't. Then, the #div2 mouseenter is fired and hovering is set to true after it's already needed. When you leave #div2, hovering is set to false, and the cycle repeats. The code in "//action here" is executed whether or not you're hovering over div2.

Answer (score 0):

I followed Nicolas' answer and tried but as per Joel's comment it won't work. So tried some changes in the same code and now its working for me.

```
var hovering = false;

$("#div").mouseleave(function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if(!hovering) {
            //Action Here
        }
    }, 0);
});

$("#div2").mouseenter(function () {
    hovering = true;
});
$("#div2").mouseleave(function () {
    hovering = false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could put the action within a mouseOver for the HTML tag, and simply set a variable or bool to detect if you'd just come from the original div.

mouseOver handlers for the other divs with stopPropagation would prevent any interference.

That's how a lot of turning off light boxes or tool tip functions would be built.